# How do I make my kahoot botter generate random answers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

So, I tried to make a kahoot botter using the kahoot.js-updated library, and I found this code to answer random questions

```js
const Kahoot = require("kahoot.js-updated");
var kahoots = []
for (var i = 0; i < bot_count; i++) {
    kahoots.push(new Kahoot);
    kahoots[i].join(pin, name+" "+String(i)).catch(error => {
        console.log("join failed " + error.description + " " + error.status)
    });
kahoots[i].on("QuestionStart", (question) => {
        question.answer(
            Math.floor(
                Math.random() * question.quizQuestionAnswers[question.questionIndex]
            )
        );
    });
```

now, when I try it, the bots join, but they don't answer questions, and then it gives me this error: `Math.random() * question.quizQuestionAnswers[question.questionIndex]
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`

But I don't know how it isn't defined, because its part of the library.

Comment: unless `question.quizQuestionAnswers[question.questionIndex]` should provide a number I dont see how that would work.

Comment: yeah, it should

Comment: then I am afraid your dont understand what that piece of code is doing, more specifically `Math.random() * question.quizQuestionAnswers[question.questionIndex]`

Answer (score 0):

To generate random answer use the `Math.random()` function to generate random index for the array so , in your example it is `quizQuestionAnswers` and then select the corresponding answer option, and you should know if the `quizQuestionAnswers` array is undefined or empty this method won't work

so this is example

```js
kahoots[i].on("QuestionStart", (quiz) => {
    if (quiz.quizQuestionAnswers && quiz.quizQuestionAnswers.length > 0) {
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.quizQuestionAnswers.length);
        quiz.answer(quiz.quizQuestionAnswers[randomIndex]);
    }
});
```

**You should know the code will skip the question and not submit an answer if it still undefined or null**

this what i understand from your explain , also you can provide some of console.log to be aware about

Comment: its not supposed to be undefined

Comment: it did not work

Comment: The error message you're getting indicates that the `quizQuestionAnswers` array is undefined or empty, which means that the library is not able to retrieve the answer options for the current question. 
so please log step by step to let me know whare the error

Comment: so the kahoot bot joins the game, no errors, but when i start the game, i run into that error